# How to specify video bit rate mode is used in .mp4 file

Tags: ffmpeg, mode, bitrate, mediainfo

I have a problem about get media info of .mp4 file. I want to get video bit rate mode of the .mp4 file.

I used to ffmpeg and mediainfo tool.

- ffmpeg don't have (or show) video_bit_rate_mode field.

  Command: ffprobe -show_streams -i "file.mp4"
- mediainfo tool have video_bit_rate_mode field. It's fine when open with some formats, however, this field is not shown when I open with .mp4 file.

Please help me how to specify video bit rate mode is used in .mp4 file.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Does MP4 container have any bitrate modes? I can imagine the video codec (H.264) alone could have variable bitrates but how that info can be obvious once inside an MP4 file is beyond me. Anyways with H.264 you encode 1-pass for constant and use 2-pass encoding for the equivalent of variable bitrate. Unless that information can be found in the video bytes you may never know unless you make the file.

Answer (score 1):

FYI, bit rate mode detection is planned in MediaInfo but is unfortunately not in the list of priorities for the moment. I hope to have some free time soon for implementing it.
Jérôme, developer of MediaInfo

Comment: Thanks Jérôme, I am looking forward to see your newest MediaInfo version.
Moreover, Do you have any way can get the bit rate mode?